# how to reference database variables inside a Coldfusion8 cffunction tag?

Tags: variables, coldfusion, cffunction

I'm doing my first steps in Coldfusion8. I managed to setup a component/service with a cffunction I'm calling.

Inside the function I need to contruct a 2x2 table with errors and corresponding error messages. Error messages are multi-language and stored in a MySQL table.

**Problem:**

I can't find a way to reference my variables from inside a *CFFunction* tag. This does not work:

```
// select from database
<cfparam name="Session.Sprache" default="DE">
    <cfquery datasource="iln" name="texte">
        SELECT *
        FROM languages
        WHERE sprache = "#Session.lang#"
     </cfquery>

<cffunction name="createErrMsgsLog" returntype="object">
    // create and populate 
    <cfset allErrMsgs=ArrayNew(2)>
    <cfset allErrMsgs[1][1]="firma">
    // not defined
    <cfset allErrMsgs[1][2]="#tx_validate_firma#">
    ....
 </cffunction>
```

**Question:**
How can I reference my variables aka #tx_validate_firma# correctly inside *CFfunction*. They are always undefined.

**EDIT**:
Ok. This seems to work:

Inside **application.cfc** I'm calling:

```
<cfinvoke component="services.errorMsg"
     method="createErrMsgsLog"          
     returnvariable="errMsgs">
</cfinvoke>
```

Inside **errorMsg.cfc** I'm doing:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="errorMsg">    
    <cffunction name="createErrMsgsLog">
        <cfquery datasource="mine" name="texte">
            SELECT *
            FROM sprachen
            WHERE sprache = "#Session.Sprache#"
        </cfquery>
        <cfoutput query="texte">
            // column name = value
            <cfset "#trim(bezeichner)#" = "#trim(textinhalt)#">
        </cfoutput>
        // build array
        <cfset allErrMsgs=ArrayNew(2)>
        <cfset allErrMsgs[1][1] = "firma">
        <cfset allErrMsgs[1][2] = #tx_validate_firma#>
        ...

        <cfset errMsgs = serializeJSON(allErrMsgs)>
        <cfreturn errMsgs>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

This just seems like an awful lot of code...

Comment: is tx_validate_firma coming from your texte query? If so, you need to scope that value. and you don't need " or # when you reference your variable. Use `<cfset allErrMsgs[1][2]= texte.tx_validate_firma />` instead

Comment: Yes. texte is the query, which returns all tx_s so I can switch between languages.

Comment: are you passing that value into your function? The way your function is showing now I don't see where it is getting the value.

Comment: got it. See above. Ended up using ## :-)

Comment: you don't need the ## either. Unless your specifically outputting code you almost never need to use the ##.

Comment: Good. Makes the whole thing smaller. Do you want to post an answer, then I'll check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a best practices answer here. When referencing a variable you can just reference the name, no need to use ##.

For example
`<cfset "#trim(bezeichner)#" = "#trim(textinhalt)#">`

Can be `<cfset "#trim(bezeichner)#" = trim(textinhalt)>`

This doesn't solve your undefined problem, but is something you should follow moving forward (don't bother cleaning up old code), but this makes it much more readable imo.

Answer (score 0):

To use a value inside a function, you need to pass the value into the function as an argument value, eg:

```
<cffunction name="createErrMsgsLog" returntype="object">
    <cfargument name="someName" [etc]>
```

And then reference it as arguments.someName within the function.

Whilst you *can* break out of your function's internal scope and access variables from the main line, it's not considered particularly good practice to do so.

Another consideration is perhaps to abstract your functions out into component definitions in a CFC file, rather than just defining them within your "mainline" code.  This makes for tidier, more coherent code, and makes it more reusable.  That said, there's often justification for having a one-off function defined inline, too.  But it's perhaps worth investigating:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/buildingComponents_01.html#1266855

Comment: That was my idea. I inherited about 50 pages each with a ton of Javascript client-side form validation (using text values from MySQL). I'm using validval() Jquery plugin now and wanted to make a central cfc file containing all error message, which I could output as JSON right before calling validval, which hopefully makes the error messages available to the plugin. I'm pasting what I did just now above. Seems to work. Can you tell me if this is good/bad practive?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here to think about.  Not so much an answer as some observations:

Please, for the sanity of yourself, those who have to maintain your code, and those who want to help, don't use "select *" in queries.  From the comments that I've seen here, tx_validate_firma is returned in the query named texte.  If the code explicitly said:

```
<cfquery datasource="iln" name="texte">
    SELECT tx_validate_firma, etc
    FROM languages
    WHERE sprache = "#Session.lang#"
 </cfquery>
```

we'd all know where the value came from.  Oh, and please look at using cfqueryparam in your where clause.

I'm assuming that this works, though it seems odd:

```
<cfset allErrMsgs[1][2] = #tx_validate_firma#>
```

Because the scope of tx_validate_firma isn't explicitly stated, we outsiders are left scratching our heads, as might someone trying to maintain this later.

```
<cfset allErrMsgs[1][2] = texte.tx_validate_firma>
```

Note that you don't need to use # in assignments like this.  Generally within a ColdFusion tag you won't need them unless you are inside quotation marks.  Something like this:

```
<cfset fullName = "#firstName# #middleInitial# #lastName#">
```

Comment: Thanks. I inherited sort of a mess and am starting to wade through - Agree on cfparam, already changed this after finding out what it does... Regarding the tx_validate_firma - this is one entry out of 200+ error messages stored in a table in serveral languages. So I thought I'd construct a 2-column object, populate with name+message using variables such as "tx_validate_firma" (first message out of 200) to fill the object. On language changes, I'm reconstructing this object, so the user should always have his language error messages. Guess this cna be done eaiser, but still learning...